# magento2 custom javascript code

Tags: magento2, javascript

can anybody tell me, how to add cusom javascript code to template in magento2 ?

I add to view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<script src_type="url" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js" />
```

and its work.

But when I add

```
<script>alert('test');</script>
```

its not work.

All in one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Vie$
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <script src_type="url" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js" />
        <script>alert('test');</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" templ$
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

How to do this?

Comment: to give a better answer, can you tell us where you are placing the `<sript>` tags? are you in a phtml? and is this in a custom theme?

Comment: I add whole code to my message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It will not work.**

Magento parsing engine doesn't recognize `<script>alert('test')</script>` in layout xml. (files with .xml extension)

You need to add `<script>alert('test')</script>` to appropriate template file. (files with .phtml extension)